# Is .NET Core Runtime backwards compatible with previous releases?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-1.0

If I've installed the latest version of the .NET Core Runtime (as of now, that's version 2.2.3):

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

Is that one installation backwards-compatible with previous releases of .NET Core?

For example, will the above installation be compatible with an app which targets:

- netcoreapp1.0
- netcoreapp2.0
- netcoreapp2.1
- netcoreapp2.2

I realize that the .NET runtimes can be installed side-by-side.  However, that does not answer my question. Is the one 2.2 installation backwards compatible with previous releases, such that additional runtimes are not necessary?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

*Edit*
.NET Core 3.x SDK has been released. Unlike v2.2 and the previous releases before it, this version does *not* support the ability to target previous runtimes (i.e. netcoreapp2.2, netcoreapp2.1, etc)

### **tldr;**

Yes. By installing .NET Core Runtime 2.2.3, you can run apps which target netcoreapp2.0, netcoreapp2.1, and netcoreapp2.2, without requiring additional runtimes to be installed.

### **Explanation**

Microsoft:

> ...NET Core runtime updates are compatible within a major version
> 'band' such as 1.x and 2.x.

In other words:
(Minor updates within the same major release are backwards compatible)

Microsoft:

> Additionally, newer releases of the .NET Core SDK generally maintain
> the ability to build applications that target previous versions of the
> runtime in a compatible manner

In other words:
(The latest SDK can target previous runtimes)

Microsoft:

> In general, you only need the latest SDK and latest patch version of
> the runtimes required for your application.

In other words:
(Generally speaking, you should only need to install the latest SDK/runtime)

Microsoft:

> Over time, as you install updated versions of the .NET Core runtime
> and SDK, you may want to remove outdated versions of .NET Core from
> your machine. Removing older versions of the runtime may change the
> runtime chosen to run shared framework applications

In other words:
(As you install additional SDKs/runtimes side-by-side over time, you should occasionally remove older versions, in favor of the latest)

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?tabs=windows

### .NET Core Versioning

According to documentation:

> ".NET Core 2.1" refers to the .NET Core Runtime version number. The
> .NET Core Runtime has a major/minor/patch approach to versioning that
> follows semantic versioning.

In other words, .NET Core runtime releases follow the [Semantic Versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/index#semantic-versioning) scheme:

**[Major].[Minor].[Patch]**

Where:

- Major upgrades introduce breaking changes
- Minor upgrades are feature upgrades that are backwards-compatible with previous minor releases
- Patch upgrades are generally bug fixes or security patches to existing features (also backwards compatible with previous minor releases)

So, the answer to the above question is based on Semantic Versioning:

- Major upgrades are not backwards compatible with the *previous* major version
- Minor and/or patch upgrades are backwards-compatible within the *same* version

With this understanding, when .NET Core apps are built/published/restored, they target a major release and feature set as indicated by the major/minor version numbers found in the runtime name.  So, **netcoreapp2.2** is backwards compatible with **netcoreapp2.1**, which, in turn, is backwards-compatible with **netcoreapp2.0**.  But all are incompatible with **netcoreapp1.x** or **netcoreapp3.x**.

With one installation of .NET Core 2.1.5 runtime, and assuming a framework-dependent publish deployment, you would be able to run apps targeting:

- netcoreapp2.0
- netcoreapp2.1

But not:

- netcoreapp1.0 (incompatible)
- netcoreapp2.2 (not yet supported)

If there are multiple runtimes installed, then the exact runtime is chosen based on the latest runtime installed with the highest patch.

### About the SDK

The SDK is not based on Semantic Versioning. However, each SDK targets a maximum .NET Core Runtime, and supports every version prior to it.

That means, you don't need to install more than one [SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) on your build server if you want to build against multiple runtimes (even though you could). The SDK already includes all the necessary runtimes to build applications on the current version (or any prior version) *out-of-the-box*.  For example, if you install .NET Core 2.2.105 SDK, you can build for netcoreapp1.0, netcoreapp2.0, netcoreapp2.1, or netcoreapp2.2. But you can't build for .NET Core 2.3, or 3.0.

**An Example**

Suppose I have a build server, which has the latest .NET Core SDK installed
([SDK 2.2.105 - 2.2.3 Runtime](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.2.105-windows-x64-installer)).

Although, SDK 2.2.105 is installed, I might want to build and publish a .NET Core 2.1 app:

```
dotnet publish 
     /p:Configuration=Release -r win-x64 --self-contained false
     /p:IsWebConfigTransformDisabled=true --framework netcoreapp2.1
     /p:DebugSymbols=false /p:DebugType=None
```

- `/p:Configuration=Release` - configure for Release
- `-r win-x64` - target Windows deployment (rather than portable). For a complete list refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog.
- `--self-contained false` - Framework dependent deployment (requires runtime to be installed on host)
- `/p:IsWebConfigTransformDisabled=true` - do not transform web.config to avoid errors with the default web.config generated by Visual Studio (may be needed when migrating from 2.1 to 2.2)
- `--framework netcoreapp2.1` - explicitly target a runtime framework
- `/p:DebugSymbols=false /p:DebugType=None` - disable .PDB files

This build could be installed on a Production server with the latest runtime [.NET Core Runtime + Hosting Bundle 2.2.3](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.2.3-windows-hosting-bundle-installer) - no other runtimes (or SDK) are necessary

Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Where are you getting this information? Some of it is kind of misleading/wrong. In particular, if your application targets netcoreapp2.1, it will need runtime 2.1 to run. It will not work with runtime 2.2.

Comment: See the links from Microsoft that I included... I have also tested this to verify.

Comment: @OmairMajid Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?tabs=windows

Comment: "In general, you only need the ... latest patch version of the runtimes required for your application" seems to disagree with you, no? Patch is the last digit of the x.y.z version. Am I reading something wrong?

Comment: .NET Core runtime updates are compatible within a major version band. Have you tried installing the latest 2.2.3 runtime, and executed an app that targets netcoreapp2.1... are you saying it should not work, or that it will work, but its bad practice.  The general guidance is to use the latest patch, but read the rest of the article.

Comment: I was saying that it wont work. But I just tested it and it does. You are correct. Sorry about that.

Comment: @pixelbits Can I install a web API which is built using .net core 2.1 on a server that has .net core 1.0 installed ? Can I just install .net core 2.1 hosting pacakge on IIS and I am good to go ?

Comment: You need the latest 2.x runtime and hosting package.  It will not work with the 1.0 runtime.

Comment: Where is it documented that the 3.x SDK can't build .NET Core apps of previous versions?

Answer (score 4):

A few usage examples demonstrate the behavior, if you target 2.0:

1. 2.0 is specified. 2.0.5 is the highest patch version installed. 2.0.5 is used.
2. 2.0 is specified. No 2.0.* versions are installed. 1.1.1 is the highest runtime installed. An error message is displayed.
3. 2.0 is specified. No 2.0.* versions are installed. 2.2.2 is the highest 2.x runtime version installed. 2.2.2 is used.
4. 2.0 is specified. No 2.x versions are installed. 3.0.0 is installed. An error message is displayed.

Please refer following link in Microsoft Docs
[Microsoft Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR; In 2023 I developed a webapp with .NET 5; thinking that a later release would be compatible with an earlier release, I proceed to install the Hosting Bundle for .NET 6 on a Server;

Result:

> HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime Common
> solutions to this issue: The specified version of
> Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.