# Is .NET Core Sdk backwards compatible with previous releases?

Tags: .net, .net-core, sdk

I am a bit confused. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55410399/is-net-core-runtime-backwards-compatible-with-previous-releases) which is for the runtime.
It also targets the SDK and says:

1. `Edit .NET Core 3.x SDK has been released. Unlike v2.2 and the previous releases before it, this version does not support the ability to target previous runtimes (i.e. netcoreapp2.2, netcoreapp2.1, etc)`
2. `That means, you do not need to install more than one SDK on your build server if you want to build against multiple runtimes (even though you could).`

But I can use the `global.js` with dotnet sdk 6 to target a dotnetcore 3 app.

**For me it looks like I only need the latest SDK to build all the previous, right?**

If so, how is that accomplished, will every new SDK contains all the others? Or how ms (I heard Java works the same) accomplish the backward compatibility?

Comment: It's merely saying that you can't TARGET previous releases with the new SDK.  So if, for example, you need to compile new code to run on .Net Core 2.1 host ... then you'll need to compile using a different SDK than .NET Core 3.x SDK.  .Net 5+, however, should support target netcoreapp 2.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few different things in play here.

`global.json` lets you select which SDK to use. Not which one (runtime) to target, but which SDK to use, if you have more than one SDK installed.

To select which runtime to target, use the `TargetFramework` element in your `.csproj` file. For example, `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>`

Recent versions of the SDK let you target older runtimes. A 6.0 SDK will let you target the 3.1 runtime without any issues.

Still, multiple versions of the SDK might generate different code or do things differently enough that breaks your application. Using a matching SDK and Runtime is probably the safest bet.

If you are in the middle of development (eg, `dotnet build`) or have built a Framework Dependent Application (an application that's not self contained and needs a .NET Runtime to work), you will need to install the matching runtime to run the application. A new SDK doesn't have the older runtime.

For all other (self-contained) applications, all versions of the the Runtime (current and old versions) are available as nuget packages. The SDK pulls them down and uses them when building your application.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Do you have clue how a sdk can compiled against different runtime versions? Is their a special technic for this?

Comment: Each SDK is tied to a runtime. There's no way to compile or run a 6.0 SDK, for example, against the 3.1 runtime. At least nothing that wouldn't involve a ton of non-trivial changes to .NET.