# .Net 6.0 binary compatibility with earlier .Net Core versions

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-5, .net-6.0

Couple of questions:

1. If i build an application for .Net 6.0, can it have dependencies on libraries (e.g. nuget packages) built for earlier runtimes?  In particular, i m interested in .Net 5.0 and .Net Core 3.1.  From trying it, it seems to work, but I couldn't find any official answer/guidelines from Microsoft on this.  Is there a doc link perhaps?
2. Conversely, if I have an SDK-style project built for .Net 5.0, can application built for .Net 6.0 use it, or do i have to retarget it?  What if my SDK project was built for .Net Core 3.1?
3. If the answer to the above questions is yes, then what is the purpose of [supporting multiple TFMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/multiple-target-frameworks-project-file) in the same project?  Why not just use the earliest one if it's compatible?  In particular, if i already have SDK-style project targeting .Net 5.0, would there be any reason to make it multi-target with both .Net 5.0 and .Net 6.0 included?

Comment: I found this binary compatibility table for .NET 6, as far as I understand it it is binary compatibility with previous version which would be .NET 5, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/6.0 It seems to me that you are supposed to produce separate binaries for every version you intend to support. On old .NET, what always worked for me was to build for .NET 4.5, and then the binaries/dlls worked everywhere.

Comment: Is this duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55410399/is-net-core-runtime-backwards-compatible-with-previous-releases? That question was answered saying that the runtimes are not backwards compatible (for running applications targeting older releases). It did say that you can _build_ apps targeting older runtime using new runtime. This is confusing. You can build, but not test/execute?

Comment: For the first link, i think they are talking about changes in behavior in .Net libraries, but it is still not clear if executable built for .Net 6.0 can use user library built for earlier version, or if .Net 6.0 runtime can run user library with earlier built with earlier TFM.  Although i understand that it can run into a problem if the user's library code is affected by one of those changes.

Comment: For the other question, yeah it says you can build apps (and i assume libraries) for older runtimes using latest SDK.  But doesn it mean you can link an app built with latest runtime to a library built with older runtime?  I couldn't find any info on that.

Comment: I think you can, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks. But this is probably best resolved by trying it out. I'm going to try it myself some time, and if I do, I'll report back.

Comment: Another factor here is the C# version you use. If you want C# 10, you can't compile for .NET 5, and so on. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Comment: Targeting multiple TFMs seems to make sense when you 1) want to do things differently on different TFMs, as the example with `#if NET45` shows, 2) you want to (I am guessing here, by analogy with Java) let the compiler produce a build using more modern version of the bytecode (or, to not use Java terminology, the CIL)

Comment: also, "you should be able to write a library that targets .NET Standard 2.0 and it should work on .NET Framework 4.6.1+ and .NET Core 2.0+." https://andrewlock.net/stop-lying-about-netstandard-2-support/

Comment: `<RollForward>Major</RollForward>` allowed me to run netcore 3.1 published application on .net 6. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#values